# Is my Python code a mess?

Tags: python, oop

There are two files in the scope of this problem, let's call them `file1.py` and `file2.py`.

I've imported `file2.py` into `file1.py`.

I instantiate a class in `file1.py` and I'd like to access it in `file2.py`.  I've tried referencing the object directly (just the class name) but that doesn't work.  How can I reference the object?  I don't want to move this to the same file, it'd make it messy.

Is there a non-hackish way to do this?  If not, have I implemented a faulty design?

Comment: Its near impossible to comment on your design if you only talk about "file1" and "file2", do not tell us what the objects do etc etc. also, If stuff doesn't work you should add code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the class from somewhere in File1.py to one of the classes in file.2.

You can simply pass a reference to the class when you invoke the method in file2.py where you need to use it.

Or you can write a "Set...." Method and pass the reference and store it in one of the classes in file2.py.

You could also make it a global static variable -- but you would get refused entry to the better coding clubs if you did this.

Answer (score 0):

no, it's not a mess, i just think you're accessing the object the wrong way

first, import the file in file1.py

```
import file2
```

then, call the object without forgetting the scope:

```
file2.object.method
```

if you want a direct call to object.method, your import must change

```
from file2 import object
```

then you can do

```
object.method
```

read throu [this link](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) to understand more about modules